# Deploy Cloud Service from Azure Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cloud-services

I have a Cloud Service Package file and a Service Configuration file uploaded on Azure File Storage. Now, I want to write a C# code to pull the files from the storage and upload it to the Cloud Service Staging Deployment and eventually run it as a WebJob.

I was able to achieve this using Powershell script (**Publish-AzureServiceProject**) on my local machine (with both the package and service file on my local machine) but faced issues while running it as a WebJob. Apparently, Azure PS commands are not completely supported on Azure Webjobs / Websites.

Could someone let me know how to achieve this using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I known, there are two methods to achieve your requirements.

1. using powershell commands and encapsulated powershell command using c#.
   Please refer this [document](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2014/02/06/deploying-cloud-services-to-azure-with-powershell/) about how to use Powershell to deployment cloud service. You can write code into ps file and call it using C# code.
2. using REST API to create Cloud service and Deploy your package. Please refer to these methods: 
   [create cloud service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg441304.aspx)  and [Create Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460813.aspx)

Comment: This worked for me perfectly. Thanks a lot. I used #2 for this.

Comment: Nice. Congratulations!